# Python HTTP Post with upload file and headers generated from Postman

Tags: python, http-headers, http-post, postman

I'm using `Python 2.7`.

I want to make a `HTTP POST` using `requests`, where I upload a file and a key that must go in the `HTTP Headers`.

For that I've used the application `Postman`, where it works really fine.
[image: Postman example]

On `Postman` I've added only the necessary header, which is a `Authorization` with some key.
On the `body`, Ive choosen `form-data` and then the key is an `input_image`, and they the image itself.

Now I want to replicate this into `Python2.7`, so I've chose to see the Python code on `Postman`, which was this one:

```
import requests

url = "https://foo.com/bar/stuff"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YDxkTrZu1gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"input_image\"; filename=\"C:\\Test\\projs\\Supermarket\\doritos.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YDxkTrZu1gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YDxkTrZu1gW",
    'Authorization': "myAuthorizationKey",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "0efwd6e8-051c-4ed5-8d6f-7b1bd135f4d5"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

This simply doesn't work. It has the same behaviour as if I didn't send any image using `Postman`. It looks like the payload string is not being send correctly.

**Question:**

What is wrong with this `Postman` auto-generation code in order to send a `HTTP POST` with `image upload` and with `header` at the same time in `Python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Postman is doing some logic we are not really aware of. But the package `requests` provide a way to upload images.

```
files = {'media': open('my_image.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=hearders)
```

According to the server you are sending the image to, the parameters name, this code might need to be slightly changed.

Comment: Hi @Jrmyy Thanks for that. But apparentely the web API also requests the payload I've also placed above. Is there any way to use also that? If I just use as data=payload, it complains that the payload can't be a string.

Comment: @waas1919, if you need to put the payload, maybe something like that could work :
`with open('my_image.jpg', "rb") as image_file:
    payload = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())`
And then you can use a payload, because it will be bytes (if you want, you can try to convert to bytes the payload you have in your example)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
import requests

url = 'http://iizuka.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/projects/colorization/web/'
files = {'file': ("my_img_path/myImage.jpeg", open('my_img_path/myImage.jpeg', 'rb'),'image/jpg')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

the only trick works here is your code should be same as you post request in postman, no extra headers need to be added , your post request should look like the same as it is in postman.
I could do this by changing my file to an image file and then posting it in my post request.

```
    with open('grass-small.png', 'rb') as imageFile:
        imageStr = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(imageFile.read())
    files = {'document': ('grass-small.png', imageStr ), 'document_type':(None,'grass')}
```